# Why is float left and right not working in this case?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a search box on left end and arrows on right end. Float is not working and the arrows are coming very close to search box. Also tried left:0px and right:0px. Could anyone help with this? Thank you.

```css
.candidate {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.candidate-search {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.pagearrow {
  display: flex;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-7 col-md-7">
  <div class="conatiner-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="candidate">
        <div class="candidate-search">
          <input class="filter-searchbox py-2" type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search" />
        </div>
        <div class="pagearrow">
          <span class="material-icons">arrow_back_ios</span>
          <span class="material-icons">arrow_forward_ios</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Float has no effect of flex items.

Comment: you use flexbox so float don't work in this case, just read about flex in the bootstrap guide

Comment: I would recommend against using float unless specific use cases. Flexbox is so much powerful. I'll say it out loud: you don't need float anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Float*** property is not working on **flex box** property. You can try to use
[justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) to align elements

Example:

```
justify-content: space-between;
```